# Perl regex for a digit/letter combination

Tags: regex, perl

I'm looking for a perl regex for a combination of digits and letters, with allowing for spaces and "/" and "-" characters as possible separators.

Basically, I want it to match expressions that contain a combination of letters and digits and/or separators, like this:

ATG567A 
ATG56-7A 
ATG56/7A 
ATG56 7A

But not this:

ATG-A     <---- letters and/or separators only 
567/7     <---- digits and/or separators only

Comment: `perldoc perlretut` might be helpful.

Comment: `m! ([-/ A-Z0-9]+) !x`

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, **show us specifically what you did** so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: It's not sensible to write a single regex for this. It's not *impossible*; it's just not smart.

Comment: what about this: `AT3G-` or this: `AT-/3G`?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to validate a string, it's simpler to do it as multiple checks.

```
m{^[A-Za-z0-9 /-]*\z} && /[A-Za-z]/ && /[0-9]/
```

Those can be combined into one pattern, but I advice against it.

```
m{^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9 /-]*\z}s
```

On the other hand, if you're trying to extract from a string, you'll need the following:

```
m{
   [ /-]*+
   (?:   [A-Za-z] [A-Za-z /-]*+ [0-9]
   |     [0-9]    [0-9 /-]*+    [A-Za-z]
   )
   [A-Za-z0-9 /-]*+
}x
```

Comment: (`*+` is the same as `*`, except it prevents what would be useless backtracking.)